# Returning the values of a list based on "two" parameters

Tags: r

Very new to R. So I am wondering if you can use two different parameters to get the position of both elements from a list. See the below example...

```
x <- c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B")
y <- c(which(x == "A"))

[1]  1  3  4  9 10

x[y]
[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A"

x[y+1]
[1] "B" "A" "B" "A" "B"
```

But I would like to return the positions of both y and y+1 together in the same list. My current solution is to merge the two above lists by row number and create a dataframe from there. I don't really like that and was wondering if there is another way. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what your desired output looks like?

Comment: The accepted answer repeats the 4th and the 10th elements of `x` twice because they fall into both `y` and `y+1`. Is that actually your desired output?

Comment: Yes, I want to maintain the fact that A->A and A->B as two distinct sets. This is something I didn't realize I really wanted until later in the code, so maybe unintended, but welcome nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what exactly you want, but this could help:

```
newY = c(which(x == "A"),which(x == "A")+1)
```

After that you can sort it with

```
  finaldata <- newY[order(newY)]
```

Or you do both in one step:

```
finaldata <- c(which(x == "A"),which(x == "A")+1)[order(c(which(x == "A"),which(x == "A")+1))]
```

Then you could also delete duplicates if you want to. Please tell me if this is what you wanted.